# Adding a class instance to a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have defined a class and want to add an instance to a list. How do I do that? I have tried...

```
class MyClass:
    var1=''
    var2=''

thelist = []
instance = MyClass()
instance.var1 = "hello"
instance.var2 = "world"
thelist.extend(instance)
```

and I am getting a

```
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `list.append()`, not `list.extend()`:

```
thelist.append(instance)
```

`list.extend()` expects a *sequence* of elements to add, adding them all to the list. You have just *one* element, in which case you need to use `list.append()`.

From [*More on Lists*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) in the Python tutorial:

> `list.append(x)`
>   **Add an item** to the end of the list; equivalent to `a[len(a):] = [x]`.
>
> `list.extend(L)`
>   **Extend the list by appending all the items** in the given list; equivalent to `a[len(a):] = L`.

Emphasis mine.

Demo:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     var1=''
...     var2=''
... 
>>> thelist = []
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.var1 = "hello"
>>> instance.var2 = "world"
>>> thelist.append(instance)
>>> thelist
[<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x106d19d40>]
>>> thelist[0].var1
'hello'
```